# How Linux Capabilities relate to zero/non-zero UID?

Tags: linux, setuid, linux-capabilities

The capabilities [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) is rather long and I do not fully understand some things.

How would look, for example, a function that decides whether we have access to CAP_NET_RAW?

Input:

- a = Effective uid is 0
- b = There are some real/saved/whatever uid that is 0
- c = CAP_NET_RAW is +e
- d = CAP_NET_RAW is +i
- e = CAP_NET_RAW is +p
- f = CAP_NET_RAW is excluded from the "bounding set"

Output:

- x = we can now call `socket` and not get EPERM
- y = after some trickery (not involving filesystem-based `chmod +s` or `setcap` access elevations or connecting to external helpers), e.g. with `capsetp` we can finally allow ourselves to open the raw socket.

As I currently understand it is something like this:

- x = !f  && (a || c)
- y = !f && (b || a || c || e)

How is it in reality?

Comment: If the effective UID is 0, then you still need to have `CAP_NET_RAW` in either the permitted or the effective set (but when the uid is changed to 0, the P set gets copied to the E set), so IIUC `x = !f && (c || a && e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs a bit more, now it seems like it is this:

```
x = c
can_regain_caps_without_execve = (a || b) && !NO_NEW_PRIVS && (!SECBIT_NO_SETUID_FIXUP || ( CAP_SETPCAP && !SECBIT_NO_SETUID_FIXUP_LOCKED))
y = c || e || can_regain_caps_without_execve
```

I.e.

- Zero/nonzero uid is only meaningful when it changes and "root hacks" are active;
- Only effective capabilities are used for checks; everything else is capability management;
- Bounding set and inherited capabilities are about execve => out of scope for this answer.